# Receiving error through special characters in textbox : A potentially dangerous Request

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net

I am using c# , asp.net.

I have a textbox in which gets pre loaded with the values from DB.
These values contains some special characters Eg.`Ll&#250;ria`

I get error -

> A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (SBItem:ItemBoxContentsDefinition:SecondaryOptio
> nSummary:_ctl12:_ctl5="...oger de Llúria, Barcelona...").

What could be the way , I could save it as what it is in textbox ?

Edit 1 : I applied validateRequest=false

still getting same error.

```
<%@ Page language="c#" AutoEventWireup="false" Inherits="TAN.Pages.BackOffice.BookingManagement.BookingDetails" ValidateRequest="false" %>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client)

Comment: @GSerg no. getting error with that also

Comment: Then why did you accept an answer that tells you to do [just one of the things](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3368769/11683) that are listed in the duplicate, not even mentioning all the other things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to web.config and set

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
```

[Reference](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/297679/A-potentially-dangerous-Request-Form-value-was-det)